# What does C in C and C++ refer to?

Tags: c++, c

Please let me know what this C in **C** programming and C++ programming is used for? I'm serious as this question was put in front of me in an interview.

Comment: i expect the wikipedia page would tell you this

Comment: Whilst in some ways a silly interview question, I guess this is actually a strangely effective way of weeding people out when you think about it -- the sort of people who know about programming language history are generally also the sort of people who care about coding. And a high level of interest in something often makes you better at it.

Comment: It stands for "Crappy Interviewer".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing at all. It was just the successor of B, which was a stripped-down version of BCPL.

Comment: Isn't BCPL involved somewhere.

Comment: Maybe the "C" is because it follows B in "BCPL"? Would the successor of C need to be called "P"?

Answer (score 7):

> The "C" in C++ has a long history. Naturally, it is the name of the language Dennis Ritchie designed. C's immediate ancestor was an interpreted descendant of BCPL class B designed by Ken Thompson. BCPL was designed and implemented by Martin Richards from Cambridge University while visiting MIT in the other Cambridge. BCPL in turn was Basic CPL, where CPL is the name of a rather large (for its time) and elegant language developed jointly by the universities of Cambridge and London.
>
> Before the London people joined the project, "C" stood for **Cambridge**. Later, "C" officially stood for **Combined**. Unofficially, "C" stood for **Christopher** because Christopher Strachey was the main power behind CPL. [Bjarne Stroustrup, *The Design and Evolution of C++*, page 64]

Answer (score 5):

`C` is the letter in the alphabet after `B`, and [B was the programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%28programming_language%29) upon which `C` was based.

Comment: `s/for/of/;` /Grammar Nazi (+1)

Comment: @Bill ONeal: but you shouldn't end a sentence with 'of' - 'dangling participle' or something ;)

Comment: @sje397: This is true. (On the other hand, "for" also breaks that rule. (ending a sentence with a preposition))

Comment: @Bill ONeal, @sje397, English is not my native language, so feel free to edit my post and fix any errors you find :-)

Comment: @Billy, sje397: "That is the [sort of nonsense](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/top-ten-grammar-myths.aspx) up with which [I will not put](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/ending-prepositions.aspx)." – Churchill / Though if we're really going down that road, could someone at least fix the run-on sentence?

Comment: @Billy: Two independent clauses improperly joined: 1) C is after B in the alphabet and 2) both name successive programming languages.  It needs punctuation (comma plus conjunction, semicolon, period/full-stop, etc.) to fix.

Comment: @Fred: Missing comma != run on. Run on == 3 or more clauses joined using conjunctions, i.e. "I went to the store, and I went to the park, and I watched the little birdies fly all around, and I got back on the bus, and then I went back home."

Comment: @Billy: I've never heard *three* or more was required even among the various ways people disagree on how to define it.  And there is definitely disagreement, just like programming style debate. :)  "Two independent clauses improperly joined" is the most useful and succinct definition I've ever found, though it does tend toward the inclusive side of "run-on sentence" definitions.

Comment: @Fred: I can't believe I argued about this. Whatever. Point is it's fixed.

Comment: @Billy: I didn't mean to be bitter; just found it hard to believe you and sje were ignoring a real problem (like using i.e. instead of e.g.) to focus on a myth.

Comment: @Fred: Lol -- I didn't mention the preposition thing. I fixed it while I was there though. (BTW, never understood Churchill's sentence, given that it would have been better said "I will not put up with this sort of nonsense"..)

Comment: @Billy: It's been miscopied for nearly a century and I certainly didn't look it up before typing here, so that combined with (slight) cultural and rhetorical differences since then could explain it.  Of course it sounds mangled on purpose — but I hoped the references list in the second link (which was only found through a quick search) would be the more valuable to anyone interested.  Curiously, the link has a comment stating this rule arose when studying Greek and Latin was more popular, and supposedly (as I don't know myself) in those languages it is *never* okay to end with a preposition.